# Exact string match with parantheses

Tags: python, regex

I've been using word boundaries to look up exact words in a string but just learned that they ignore non-word characters.

So when I look for "height" in the string "height (in stories)" I get the results I expect:

```
p = re.compile(r'\b%s\b' % 'height')
p.search('height (in stories)') # match
```

But when I look for "height (in stories)" in the string "height (in stories)" I don't get a match:

```
p = re.compile(r'\b%s\b' % 'height (in stories)')
p.search('height (in stories)') # no match
```

How can I get the parentheses recognized?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but have you tried to escape the parantheseses?

Comment: If you are looking for a literal string, you don't need regex.

Comment: @JoelCornett I hadn't tried escaping. Just did, but still no match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two problems.

1. You need to use  [`re.escape(text)`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape) to create a regular expression that matches the string `text`.
2. There's no word boundary between a parenthesis and the end of the string.

Comment: I didn't think about escaping, but even after doing so, I get no match.

Comment: for #2: The python docs actually say this: "Note that formally, \b is defined as the boundary between a \w and a \W character (or vice versa), or between \w and the beginning/end of the string" -- http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Comment: @AbidA: As I said, you have *two* problems. You've fixed *one* of them. To fix the other you could use `(?!\w)` instead of the final `\b`.

Answer (score 1):

`p = re.compile(r'\bheight \(in stories\)')`

Answer (score 0):

When using regular expressions, you should *read their syntax*.

The `(` and `)` characters have a special meaning in regular expressions, if you want to match the characters literally, you need to escape them. Just like the dot `.`...

Consider using `re.escape`.